# Rails upload android webview

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, webview

I have a Rails web application, and I hired someone to develop an android and iphone app for it, which is just a webview opening the website.

In the web app, the user can upload an avatar picture. But uploading is not working from the app, it just doesn't open the dialog box to choose the file.

Edit: I just did a test with a very simple code

```
<html> <body> <input type="file" name="test" /> </body> </html>
```

and it still doesn't open the dialog box to choose the file

Anyone has an idea why this happens? Is it something to be handled by web or app side?

Comment: maybe hire a better developer!! joke's aside...cant help  you without you posting any code

Comment: There are many ways to do an upload so you will need to explain more? How is the JS sending it? Or is it just a plain HTML form? And how are you getting it in Rails?

Comment: I just did a test here, and if I write a code as simple as <html>
  <body>
    <input type="file" name="test" />
  </body>
</html> it still doesn't open the dialog box to choose the file